# Does my device need to always have status = connected to export data from IoT Central to blob,event hubs,data explorer?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

I am trying to export data with my device disconnected but not working for me. I would like to know if my device needs to be always with status = connected to export data from IoT Central to blob, event hubs, data explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked and tested by myself:
The device really needs to be connected otherwise the data export will not work.